# Discover device by using UPnP?

Tags: c++, upnp

I'm using UPnP to discover IP Camera, I sent the following UDP multicast to devices

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
MAN: "ssdp:discover"
MX: 15
ST: ssdp:all
```

But There are some devices that were not sent back response message.

In my case, Local network involve a PC, a IP Cameras Panasonic and a IP Camera Axis.

But There are PC and IP Camera Panasonic responded, and IP Camera Axis didn't respond.

I'm sure that the IP Camera Panasonic has enabled UPnP in its setting.

Someone can tell me, how to solve this.

Many Thanks,

T&T

Comment: Verify if *another* UPnP service can see "IP Camera Axis" (or whichever device didn't respond). If it can't (but can also detect the other devices), then it might not be an issue with the code.

Comment: @user2864740: Thank you, I have just search for UPnP Discover App. And I found only a app in Android, I tried to run it, but I only detect PC, not detect any Camera. So can you give me other UPnP app?

Comment: Device Spy from [Intel UPnP Tools](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-for-upnp-technology-download-tools) is a pc app which lists all UPnP devices on your network.

Comment: For linux, [gupnp-tools](http://wiki.gnome.org/GUPnP/) is available in most distributions and includes gupnp-universal-cp which is similar to Device Spy.

Comment: Thank all, I used the following topic to solve my problem
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382290(VS.85).aspx
But I have other problems with this topic, please see my other question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840016/discover-devices-by-using-upnp-api